# How to read a Firestore timestamp in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to read a timestamp from my Firestore database and ultimately convert it to a date, but for some reason my code doesn't seem to be returning anything. Instead, it only seems to use the default value that I provide, which is 0, so it always reads as Jan 1, 1970.

The document I'm trying to read in Firestore includes a field called date, which has a type of timestamp. There are other fields in the document, but to keep things simple I've left those out from this question. For reference, the other fields from the document are successfully read.

I've tried the below code. Note that I have imported Firebase to the class:

```
   surveyDataCollectionRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let timestamp = data["date"] as? TimeInterval ?? 0
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
                    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
                    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
                    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                    
                    let newSurvey = Survey(date: strDate)
                    
                    self.surveys.append(newSurvey!)
                    self.currentSurveys = self.surveys
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document data that you're expecting to receive.  Without knowing what's actually in that document, there's not much we can say.  If your document doesn't have a field called "date", that might explain the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question with extra information. The document does have a field named "date", so that doesn't seem to be it. When I print to the console, I actually do receive the timestamp too...

Comment: I would suggest adding **all** of that debugging information to the question so we can observe what you observe.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is `date` a native Firestore timestamp or a number? Because the way you handle the date on the client suggests you want a Unix timestamp (an integer).

Answer (score 1):

After even more trial and error I found that the below code seemed to be able to get me a date as a String value (and in the correct format that I was aiming for:

```
if let timestamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp {
    let date = timestamp.dateValue()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    strDate = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: date))"
}
```